# T/SQL - Trying to convert col to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

DDL/DML http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d69c/1

Desired Output:

```
Country_    State_  FamilyTag   ChildTag    Name    HouseHold   IsReachable Rank_
US          CA      Family A    Child A     Ch A1   1           1           1
US          CA      Family B    Child A     Ch A1   1           1           2
US          CA      Family C    Child A     Ch A1   1           1           3
US          CA      Family B    Child B     Ch B1   3           1           1
US          CA      Family A    Child B     Ch B1   3           1           2
US          CA      Family C    Child B     Ch B1   3           1           3
US          CA      Family C    Child C     Ch C1   2           1           1
US          CA      Family A    Child C     Ch C1   2           1           3
US          CA      Family B    Child C     Ch C1   2           1           2

"Child[n]Tag" field data should go in "ChildTag" field.
"Child[n]Name" field data should go in "Name" field.
"ChildFamilyTag[n]" field data should go in "FamilyTag" field.
"ChildFamilyRank[n]" field data should go in "Rank_" field.
"Child[n]HouseHold" field data should go in "Household" field.
"Child[n]IsReachable" field data should go in "IsReachable" field.
```

Getting NULLs instead of above desired output...please help

Note:

```
# of "ChildFamily%" columns can vary (right now, it has 3 sets...but could be 2,3, and etc.
Also, my example shows only one record, there could be more. :)
```

Thank you

p.s. if you need me to post code here, kindly let me know.

Comment: Have you looked at `PIVOT` queries?  That might greatly simplify your logic.

Comment: I thought PIVOT would be useful if I want to aggregate things. I am not trying to aggregate anything. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Doesnt have to aggregate, you can pivot over a row_number, or `N` in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is pretty much along the way there.  But you are missing conditions in the `case` statements.  Adding new conditions seems pointless, when some arithmetic on `N` solves the problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Country_
            , State_
            , (CASE WHEN N = 1 THEN 1
                    WHEN N = 2 THEN 2
                    WHEN N = 3 THEN 3
                    WHEN N = 4 THEN 4
                    WHEN N = 5 THEN 5
                    WHEN N = 6 THEN 6
                    WHEN N = 7 THEN 7
                    WHEN N = 8 THEN 8
                    WHEN N = 9 THEN 9 END) AS ParentNo
            , (CASE WHEN N = 1 THEN [Child1FamilyTag1]
                    WHEN N = 2 THEN [Child1FamilyTag2]
                    WHEN N = 3 THEN [Child1FamilyTag3]
                    WHEN N = 4 THEN [Child2FamilyTag1]
                    WHEN N = 5 THEN [Child2FamilyTag2]
                    WHEN N = 6 THEN [Child2FamilyTag3]
                    WHEN N = 7 THEN [Child3FamilyTag1]
                    WHEN N = 8 THEN [Child3FamilyTag2]
                    WHEN N = 9 THEN [Child3FamilyTag3] END) AS FamilyTag
            , (CASE WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 1 THEN [Child1Tag]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 2 THEN [Child2Tag]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 3 THEN [Child3Tag] END) AS ChildTag
            , (CASE WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 1 THEN [Child1Name]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 2 THEN [Child2Name]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 3 THEN [Child3Name] END) AS Name
            , (CASE WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 1 THEN [Child1HouseHold]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 2 THEN [Child2HouseHold]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 3 THEN [Child3HouseHold] END) AS HouseHold
            , (CASE WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 1 THEN [Child1IsReachable]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 2 THEN [Child2IsReachable]
                    WHEN (N + 2) / 3 = 3 THEN [Child3IsReachable] END) AS IsReachable
            , (CASE WHEN (N % 3) = 1 THEN [Child1FamilyRankA]
                    WHEN (N % 3) = 2 THEN [Child1FamilyRankB]
                    WHEN (N % 3) = 0 THEN [Child1FamilyRankC]
                END) AS Rank
FROM Temp TI CROSS JOIN
   (SELECT 1 AS N
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 5
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 6 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 7
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 8 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 9) N
    ) T;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d69c/13) is the SQL Fiddle.

EDIT (in response to comment):

Your original query is

```
        , (CASE WHEN N = 1 THEN [Child1FamilyRankA]
                WHEN N = 2 THEN [Child1FamilyRankB]
                WHEN N = 3 THEN [Child1FamilyRankC]
                WHEN N = 4 THEN [Child2FamilyRankA]
                WHEN N = 2 THEN [Child2FamilyRankB]
                WHEN N = 3 THEN [Child2FamilyRankC]
                WHEN N = 7 THEN [Child3FamilyRankA]
                WHEN N = 2 THEN [Child3FamilyRankB]
                WHEN N = 3 THEN [Child3FamilyRankC] END) AS Rank_
```

I don't know why the values are arranged as they are for this `rank_`, but you can keep using them.  I think I replaced them with something else.

Comment: I don't know if it's the high volume on my TV that's distracting me or just tired...your sln seems very slick. Will need to dissect the logic to grasp it a bit. Merci beaucoup for your help!

Comment: Oh wait! @Gordon Linoff,  The rank doesn't seem to be in sync. For Family C, Child C, the rank should be 1,3,2 for Family C, Family A, and Family B, respectively. However, the above query is returning 1,2,3 respectively...can you please assist.

Comment: @user1569220 . . . It is hard to tell what the rules are for assigning values.  You can explicitly write the `case` statement to get the order that you need.

Comment: sorry if the field name is confusing but we are not calculating the RANK_ based on any "rank" function. The value for Rank_ field is coming from ChildFamilyRank[n] field. So for the last three records, the Rank_ field should have 1, 3, 2 (based on ChildFamilyRankA, ChildFamilyRankB, ChildFamilyRankC instead of 1, 2, 3). I honestly don't think populating Rank_ field by explicitly defining the "order" (the value is not associated in any order...it's the fields). I will further think about this. Merci!

Comment: Woohoo!!! It works (just updated the N = # after the N = 4 case statement). Thanks @Gordon Linoff ! The values in the original query are arranged in the way because I suspect the value for ChildFamilyRank[n] will not always be in asc order. This is simply brilliant work. Off to try some more scenarios now. :)